# java script validation is not working i tried my best

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    function validate() {

        var v1 = document.myform.ename.value;
        var v2 = document.myform.eid.value;
        if (v1 == "" || v1 == null) {
            alert("enter the user name");
        }

        if (v2.length <= 4 && v2.length == "") {
            alert("enter the pwd greater then 4 character");
        }

    }
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor=black>
    <form name="myform" onsubmit="validate">
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" width="100%"><font size="5"> Login</font></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ename"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="Password" name="eid"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="Button" value="Submit">
                    <td><input type="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2"><a href="register.html"> <font color=white>Register
                                Here</font>
                    </a></td>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

here i posted my code when i try to validate html page it doesn't  give output what problem is in??
here i posted my code when i try to validate html page it doesn't  give output what problem is in??

Comment: Change the name to an ID, and then use `document.forms.myForm`.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, not just code dump and the same question asked twice... Also change your title to a more descriptive one. If you don't it will probably get closed and you will get downvoted for asking very poorly.

Comment: script tag should be at the end inside your body tag

Comment: it should be `onsubmit="validate()"` with the `()`

Comment: many problems here, first, if you don't do `event.preventDefault();` your form will be submitted anyway after your alerts, it should also be `v2.length <= 4 || v2.length == ""` (or and not and)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things wrong in your code, I attached the corrected code below.

- First you have to change the submit button from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`
- Second try to do your on submit in javascript, that way you can pass `e` with the event info. Then you can use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from submitting.

  - Also, your boolean algebra was a little off. You had `v2.length <= 4 && v2.length == ""`, but the `&&` needs to be changed to an `||`.

```js
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  validate();
}

function validate() {

  var v1 = myform.ename.value;
  var v2 = myform.eid.value;
  if (v1 == "" || v1 == null) {
    alert("enter the user name");
  }

  if (v2.length <= 4 || v2.length == "") {
    alert("enter the pwd greater then 4 character");
  }

}
```

```html
<body bgcolor=black>
  <form name="myform" id="myform">
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" width="100%">
            <font size="5"> Login</font>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="ename"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="Password" name="eid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <td><input type="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td colspan="2">
            <a href="register.html">
              <font color=white>Register Here
              </font>
            </a>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I hope that this helps you! If you don't understand please ask, and I will help you.

Comment: I need to display the error message form itself with out pop window .it must beside the element ex- Password________  *"password must be more than 4 character" thank you

Comment: Well you could easily make an element that has the text in it, set it to `display: none`, then you display it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your button needs to be type `submit` and also as Mike stated it needs to be `onsubmit="validate()"`.

```js
function validate() {
        var v1 = document.myform.ename.value;
        var v2 = document.myform.eid.value;
        if (v1 == "" || v1 == null) {
            alert("enter the user name");
        }

        if (v2.length <= 4 && v2.length == "") {
            alert("enter the pwd greater then 4 character");
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="#" name="myform" onsubmit="validate()">
  <div>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" width="100%">
          <font size="5"> Login</font>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>User Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ename"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="Password" name="eid"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
          <td><input type="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <a href="register.html">
            <font color=white>Register Here
            </font>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```